# Can any body suggest me a set up that I can build it up to study the surface roughness of transparent polymeric fibres?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, laser, topology, polymers

I need to study the surface of nylon-6 blank fibres with a thickness of nearly 40 micrometre. I work in optics lab with many optical components such as beam splitters, lenses, mirrors, etc; can I build a system to study the topology of this fibre?

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but I did a research project in undergrad that studied the surface morphology of thin films using a Scanning Electron Microscope and, separately, an Atomic Force Microscope. Neither were built in-house, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

1. Study the surfaces using a microscope, to get a direct sense of the 3D structure of your samples.  This can work if the features you are analyzing are larger than about 1/2 the wavelength of the illuminating light.  A confocal microscope can give you better resolution.  Adjusting the focal plane up and down can help determine where features are in the vertical direction.
2. Using the same samples, illuminate the samples with a narrow collimated laser beam.  Using a high-quality lens, focus the scattered light to form the optical Fourier transform of the scattered light.  The light pattern should correspond to the sizes and arrangements of the fibers/features in the samples.  Use a polarized laser beam and view the scattered light pattern through a polarizing filter to get additional information. Different laser wavelengths may give you somewhat different results, providing yet more information.
3. Consider using a process called "[ptychography](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-20530-x)".  It is related to #2 above, but can be used to obtain extremely detailed images without lenses. Variations on the technique can be used to obtain 3D images of microstructures.

Comment: Thank you @S. McGrew
Is there any schematic diagrams, papers, references ... etc to understand the whole thing better?
and about the ptychography method, is there any free to access code to reconstruct the data?

Comment: I have not searched for ptychography code. However, you could try searching GitHub, alternatively, you could contact authors of some selected papers on ptychography.

Comment: but this method can investigate the surface of polymer fibre? as this fibre has branches on the main backbone, will the tomography be able to characterise these features?

Comment: If the features are smaller than about 1/3 micron, you will probably need to use another method, like electron microscopy.  There might be a correlation between the diffraction pattern in suggestion #2 and the branching angles in your polymer sample, but you will need to have some method to more specifically determine the features, before you can meaningfully interpret the diffraction pattern.  Are you hoping to image the molecules themselves?  That can't really be done optically.

Comment: No, I don't need to image the molecules, I have studies the thickness of two fibres with laser diffraction, and it is showed that the fibre with branches has a higher thickness, therefore I need a method to investigate this grafting process and its impact to the blank fibre surface.

Comment: Do you know the approximate thickness of the fibers?

Comment: yes nearly 40 micrometre

Comment: Those are large enough that you should be able to image them with an ordinary microscope.  Are they closely packed, or is there space between them?  And, do you have a way to isolate the fibers so that you can examine them individually?

Comment: will the topology of these fibres will be seen with an ordinary microscope?! there is space between them, I have two fibres nylon-6 blank and nylon-6 grafted with PMMA

Comment: With fibers that large, you shluld be able to use an Atomic Force Microscope.  You won't be able to assemble an AFM from miscellaneous parts, but if you are at a university there's a good chance someone there has an AFM.